# Load Query with some JSON columns in MySQL getting {Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column }

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a file into MySQL and getting error as **ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column**. The data from the file is looks like below,

```
id,name,jfield1,jfield2
1,"A","{\"Key1\": 100,\"key2\": \"Abc\"}","{}"
2,"B","{\"Key1\": 101,\"key2\": \"Def\"}","{}"
```

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jfield1` json NOT NULL,
  `jfield2` json NOT NULL
) ;
```

The load query :

```
mysql> load data local infile "/home/user/sample.csv" into table test fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'test.jfield1'.
mysql>
```

If i insert data directly into table with **insert** data is inserting properly.

```
mysql> insert into test (id,name,jfield1,jfield2) values (1,"A","{\"Key1\": 100,\"key2\": \"Abc\"}","{}");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id,name,jfield1,jfield2) values (1,"B","{\"Key1\": 110,\"key2\": \"Def\"}","{}");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+------------------------------+---------+
| id   | name | jfield1                      | jfield2 |
+------+------+------------------------------+---------+
|    1 | A    | {"Key1": 100, "key2": "Abc"} | {}      |
|    1 | B    | {"Key1": 110, "key2": "Def"} | {}      |
+------+------+------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Please someone let me know whats wrong in the query. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your JSON seems not correctly formed ..

Comment: what is the table definition of 'test'? if ```jfield2``` is not allowing ```NULL``` values I guess your second line is invalid. Also, I think JSON uses ```"``` around keys and string values. Your file uses ```'``` which may be not allowed.

Comment: i have added table definition

Comment: well... then try to either add a ```"{}"``` at the end of line 2 in your load file or change the table definition to allow ```NULL``` and try again. If it does not work, change the single quotes to double quotes in the load file by escaping them

Comment: i have added an empty json object in line2 and escaped the double quotes and still getting same error as ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'test.jfield1'.

Answer (score 0):

try this formate it may help you while insert

```
1,'A','{"Key1": 100,"key2": "Abc"}','{}'
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful. Try to add a verbal explanation of the code.

Answer (score -2):

Try and change your data to look like this. Use a `\` before the comma.

```
1,"A","{"Key1": 100\,"key2": "Abc"}","{}"
2,"B","{"Key1": 101\,"key2": "Def"}","{}"
```